# How to change Azure Git CI deployment default python version

Tags: django, python-3.x, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-deployment

Azure only supports Python version 2.7 and 3.4 in the Application settings, and I installed newer Python 3.6.2 via App Service for my django application. I followed the setup for [continuous integration with Azure & GitHub](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/microsoftimagine/2015/09/01/using-continuous-integration-with-azure-github/) and found out that deployment failed when Azure is running deployment command. Below is part of the log that shows Azure decided to use default 2.7 even tho I specified to use 3.6.2 in `web.config` file

```
Detected requirements.txt.  You can skip Python specific steps with a .skipPythonDeployment file.
Detecting Python runtime from site configuration
Detected python-2.7
Creating python-2.7 virtual environment.
...
#(and it just continue and install the requirements.txt with pip using python-2.7 which failed)
```

> Azure will determine the version of Python to use for its virtual
>   environment with the following priority:
>
> 1. version specified in runtime.txt in the root folder
> 2. version specified by Python setting in the web app configuration
>      (the Settings > Application Settings blade for your web app in the
>      Azure Portal)
> 3. python-2.7 is the default if none of the above are specified

I can't specify the version using `runtime.txt` since 3.6.2 is not a valid value for the content. It looks like Azure ignored my `web.config` and just jump to use 2.7 as the default since none of the above are specified.

As of now, I had to go in Kudu console and manually deploy my app using 3.6.2. How can I set it to use 3.6.2 as the default when deploying my code from Github?

Below is my `web.config` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="D:\home\site\wwwroot"/>
    <!-- Django apps only: change the project name to match your app -->
    <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="django.core.wsgi.get_wsgi_application()"/>
    <add key="DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE" value="mysite.settings" />
    <add key="WSGI_LOG" value="D:\home\LogFiles\wfastcgi.log"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="PythonHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule"
           scriptProcessor="D:\home\python362x86\python.exe|D:\home\python362x86\wfastcgi.py"
           resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my experience , if you're using python Extensions in the Azure Python web app , you do not have to choose Python versions in the application settings.

[image]

Please refer to the steps I did as below:

***Step 1 :*** Create azure web app and add Extensions(here is Python 3.6.2 x86)

[image]

***Step 2 :*** Prepare your `django` project and add the `web.config`.

**web.config:**

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="django.core.wsgi.get_wsgi_application()"/>
    <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="D:\home\site\wwwroot"/>
    <add key="WSGI_LOG" value="D:\home\LogFiles\wfastcgi.log"/>
    <add key="DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE" value="<your project name>.settings" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="PythonHandler" path="handler.fcgi" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="D:\home\python362x86\python.exe|D:\home\python362x86\wfastcgi.py" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script"/>
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Static Files" stopProcessing="true">
          <conditions>
            <add input="true" pattern="false" />
          </conditions>
        </rule>
        <rule name="Configure Python" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/static/.*" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="handler.fcgi/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

***Step 3 :*** Add your site URL domain to ALLOWED_HOSTS in `settings.py` in your django project

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['***.azurewebsites.net']
```

***Step 4 :*** Publish your django project via FTP or Git.

***Step 5:*** Switch to the Kudu CMD and commands `cd Python362x86` and `touch get-pip.py` and copy the content of the url `https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py` into the `get-pip.py` via Edit button, then run `python get-pip.py` to install the pip tool.

[image]

***Step 6 :*** Install `django` package or any packages you need via `python -m pip install ***`

[image]

Then access your domain url successfully.

You could also refer to the [official tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/publishing-to-azure).

Hope it helps you.

---

***Update Answer:***

According to  the screenshots and logs you provide, I see that the Python is 2.7 version is detected by the application in runtime .

I check the environment variable on KUDU and find the Python 2.7 version.

[image]

I recommend that you overwrite the Python version in environment variable with the version of the extensions Python version you used.

[image]

Please try again.

Comment: I updated my `web.config` to include <rewrite> code from your step 2, and everything else is the same. Whenever I pushed my project to git, Azure will be triggered by Github and automatically build it without me having to go into Kudu (basically step 5&6) but I'm still getting the same error from log that it's trying to build using python-2.7. See screenshot of [Deployment details](https://imgur.com/teZPVyJ) and [Deployment Log](https://imgur.com/p5uy9j5)

Comment: @Ricek Have you set python version to OFF in Application settings and restart app? Or create a new azure web app?

Comment: I never setup the python version in App settings since I created the app, the option is OFF/greyed out since I never touch that part. I also tried customize deployment script `depoly.cmd` but azure first tries to create env with python-2.7 and failed at pip install commands due to incompatible Python version and the package. Thus never get to run anything including the script

Comment: I end up using `.skipPythonDeployment` file at project root so it will stop automatically building with python-2.7 after syncing the changes from git

Comment: @Ricek  So, everything is fine now?

Comment: Yes, everything worked now. I was just running into some old auto-processing stuff that got added to App Service a few years ago as per msft support.

Comment: @Ricek OK. You could mark the answer for others' reference on the forum.Have a nice day!